# Dropdown Menu/button in Flame Game

Tags: flutter, flame

Is there a way to add a dropdown menu in flame? I want to be able to make a dropdown button in specific with values that I can select from in that you can click it and the values show below.

I've tried Flutter's dropdown button, but that is not a flame component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dropdowns I would recommend to use Flutter widgets and add them as overlays to your `GameWidget`.

Something like this:

```
GameWidget<OverlaysExample>(
  game: MyGame(),
  overlayBuilderMap: const {
   'dropdown': (BuildContext buildContext, OverlaysExample game) {
     return MyDropDownWidget();
   },
  },
  initialActiveOverlays: const ['dropdown'],
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided not to use a dropdown menu, but this might work for a text field I plan to put in my game.

Comment: @ZanX yep, it would for sure.
Could you mark the answer as accepted? :)